# Retrofitting a roof rack

Tags: car-rack

A friend is willing to sell me at a friendly price the Thule roof rack pictured below.

[image: roof rack on ground]

It's home will be a Subaru Outback that already has the crossbars (see the blue rectangles above)

[image: car with existing crossbars]

Any thoughts on how to securely attach the red-highlighted racks above to the cross-bars below?

Comment: Is this really on-topic, here? Obviously it's _related_ to cycling but it really seems to be a car question to me.

Comment: I guess my point is that any car person with experience with bike or non-bike roof-racks could probably help you.

Comment: It would be a good idea to flip the roof rack over and post a picture.  Also close-ups  of how the bike rails attach to the cross-bars.

Comment: What's that big white thing under your bike for?  Is it a special kind of training mat for under a static trainer?

Comment: I would be shocked if there were not several off-the-shelf adapter kits to mate a Thule rack to stock Subaru bars. Should be easy enough to find one online, but if you prefer you can go to a rack or outdoors shop and ask about them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on mechanics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jsf80238 no it was me being funny - implying that a bike on top of a car is just luggage; that a bike is for riding not carrying.     Good work on solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I took @Christopher Hunter's comment above an an answer, thank you:  I looked up Thule ***adapter*** and found a retail shop [near my house](https://www.rackattack.com/info/stores/denver/).  I visited that shop today and was told that adapting was not possible:  the rack attaches to the roof bar in two places ... I could purchase a back "tie-down" that was wide enough to span the roof bar, but not the front.

I ended up buying [two rockymounts brand tierods](https://rockymounts.com/products/tierod).  I have not yet installed them and can return them in case someone believes I chose poorly.

Comment: Please do let us know what they say, after you've been there.